# Group array by string

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

I have a bunch of data in array without sorting, i need to categorize the data into set and display to the public. This is how the data loop without categorisation.

```
foreach ($info as $i){
            if ($i->metadataKey==1018){
                echo $i->businessId . " - " . $i->businessName . " - " . $i->metadataValue;
            }
            if ($i->metadataKey==1021){
                echo ", " . $i->metadataValue;
                echo "<br/>";
            }
        }
```

it's a joined table and one business having numbers of metadata (associated by metadataKey and metadataValue). The following is the code i getting data from database.

```
$info = DB::table('business')
            ->leftJoin('business_meta', 'business.Id', '=', 'business_meta.businessId')
            ->get();
```

Or you may reference the following table

**Business**

> - id
> - business name

**Business_meta**

> - metadatakey
> - metadatavalue
> - businessId

one business will have couple of business meta, 1018 is state and 1021 is country

I need to assorciate it into sort array or some pattern of data to display it according to "state, country" on the public site.

Which mean, it may be something like

**California, US**

> - Business 1
> - Business 2

**Texas, US**

> - Business 3

Please advice how can i make it. Thanks.

Comment: This answer to this looks useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706359/php-array-group

Answer (score -1):

I think [usort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php) is all you need. Just create your custom function for sorting both levels of your array.