# PHP - Sum values of a matching key if 3 other key values match

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that has multiple years of total sales for several countries.  Below is small sample of the array.  Some countries had sales in several different currencies but are now converted into the same currency.  Now I need to add those total sales together where the Year, Month and Country values are the same but still keep the similar structure.

If values of ["Year"] & ["Month"] & ["Country"] match, then I need sum the values of ["Total_Sales"] and keep the same array structure.

I'm not sure where to begin.  I'm sure there is a foreach loop or 2 involved.

### Here is the array

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Year"]=>
    string(4) "2014"
    ["Month"]=>
    string(2) "12"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "NZ"
    ["Total_Sales"]=>
    float(8.25)   
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Year"]=>
    string(4) "2014"
    ["Month"]=>
    string(2) "12"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "NZ"
    ["Total_Sales"]=>
    string(6) "5.50"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Year"]=>
    string(4) "2014"
    ["Month"]=>
    string(2) "12"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "US"
    ["Total_Sales"]=>
    string(9) "10.05"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Year"]=>
    string(4) "2015"
    ["Month"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "NZ"
    ["Total_Sales"]=>
    float(9.50)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Year"]=>
    string(4) "2015"
    ["Month"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "NZ"
    ["Total_Sales"]=>
    string(6) "15.00"
  [5]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Year"]=>
    string(4) "2015"
    ["Month"]=>
    string(2) "1"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "US"
    ["Total_Sales"]=>
    string(9) "6.00"
}
```

### Here's the results that I would like:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Year"]=>
    string(4) "2014"
    ["Month"]=>
    string(2) "12"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "NZ"
    ["Total_Sales"]=>
    float(13.75)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Year"]=>
    string(4) "2014"
    ["Month"]=>
    string(2) "12"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "US"
    ["Total_Sales"]=>
    string(9) "10.05"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Year"]=>
    string(4) "2015"
    ["Month"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "NZ"
    ["Total_Sales"]=>
    float(24.50)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Year"]=>
    string(4) "2015"
    ["Month"]=>
    string(2) "1"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "US"
    ["Total_Sales"]=>
    string(9) "6.00"
}
```

Comment: Google Grouping arrays in PHP. It will get you started. Post back your code when you get stuck.

Comment: you can get help from here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706359/php-array-group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do something like

```
foreach($currentArray as $value){
    $newArraykey = $value["country"]."-".$value["Year"]."-".$value["month"]
    if(isset($newArray[$newArraykey])){
        $newArray[$newArraykey]["Total_Sales"] = $newArray[$newArraykey]["Total_Sales"] + $value["Total_Sales"];
    }else{
        $newArray[$newArraykey] = $value;
    }
}
```

$newArray would be something like

```
array(4) {
  [NZ-2014-12]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Year"]=>
    string(4) "2014"
    ["Month"]=>
    string(2) "12"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "NZ"
    ["Total_Sales"]=>
    float(13.75)
  }
  [US-2014-12]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Year"]=>
    string(4) "2014"
    ["Month"]=>
    string(2) "12"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "US"
    ["Total_Sales"]=>
    string(9) "10.05"
  }
  [NZ-2015-1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Year"]=>
    string(4) "2015"
    ["Month"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "NZ"
    ["Total_Sales"]=>
    float(24.50)
  }
  [US-2015-1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Year"]=>
    string(4) "2015"
    ["Month"]=>
    string(2) "1"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "US"
    ["Total_Sales"]=>
    string(9) "6.00"
}
```

If you do not want the keys like country-year-month they use `array_values($newArray)` this would return exactly the same array you wanted.

Comment: I have looked at something similar but couldn't get it to work right.  The code does't seem to add up the Total_Sales value.  Rather it removes the first match and returns the second with only it's total.

Comment: array(4) {
 ["NZ-2014-9"]=>
  float(13.75)
  ["US-2014-9"]=>
  string(9) "10.05"
  ["NZ-2015-9"]=>
  float(15.00)
  ["US-2015-9"]=>
  string(9) "6.00"
  }

Comment: there was some silly mistake in the code check that now.