# Query to show match information for last 2 rounds of tournament

Tags: mysql

I dont know how to achieve this.

I have 2 tables in my database:

Table 1: rounds

```
+------------+----------+---------+----------+---------------+
|  round_id  |  format  |  Size   |  poster  | tournament_id |
+------------+----------+---------+----------+---------------+
|     6      |  Single  |   12    |  Luis    |      1
|     7      |  Single  |   9     |  Daniel  |      1        |
|     8      |  Single  |   4     |  Oscar   |      1        |
+------------+----------+---------+----------+---------------+
```

Table 2: matches

```
+------------+----------+-------------+----------+----------+
|  round_id  |  player  |  position   |  score   |  winner  |
+------------+----------+-------------+----------+----------+
|     6      |  Doris   |     0       |    1     |    1     |
|     7      |  Arturo  |     0       |    3     |    1     |
|     7      |  Pablo   |     1       |    2     |    0     |
|     8      |  Ale     |     0       |    1     |    0     |
|     8      |  Maria   |     1       |    5     |    1     |
|     8      |  Roberto |     2       |    4     |    0     |
+------------+----------+-------------+----------+----------+
```

At the first table i have the rounds of the tournaments and at the second table the matches from each round, as you can see each match in a round can **have different size of players**. So i want to get all info of the rounds **BUT** just the last 2 rounds from the table "rounds", to get something like this in one query:

Result from query:

//The main key can be the round_id or numbers in order 0 to n
//

```
[7] => Array
    (
        ['poster'] => 'Daniel'
        ['format'] => 'single'

            (
                [0] => Array
                      (
                          ['player'] => 'Arturo'
                          ['score'] => 3
                       )
                [1] => Array
                       (
                          ['player'] => 'Pablo'
                          ['score'] => 2
                       )
            )

    )
[8] => Array
    (
        ['poster'] => 'Oscar'
        ['format'] => 'single'

            (
                [0] => Array
                      (
                          ['player'] => 'Ale'
                          ['score'] => 1
                       )
                [1] => Array
                       (
                          ['player'] => 'Maria'
                          ['score'] => 5
                       )
                [2] => Array
                       (
                          ['player'] => 'Roberto'
                          ['score'] => 4
                       )
            )

    )
```

So in my page i can show the last rounds uploaded, something like this:

```
+---------------------------+
|  by Daniel                |
|  Arturo (3) vs Pablo (2)  |
+---------------------------+

+---------------------------------------+      
|  by Oscar                             |
|  Ale (1) vs Maria (5) vs Roberto (4)  |
+---------------------------------------+
```

Hope a MySQL expert can help me with this :)

Comment: do they all belong to the same tournament? does this matter?

Comment: i just want to show the last rounds uploaded with the information. doesn´t matter if its from different tournament

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the `matches` table with a subquery that gets the last 2 rows in the `rounds` table.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM rounds
      ORDER BY round_id DESC
      LIMIT 2) AS r
JOIN matches AS m ON r.round_id = m.round_id
```

See [Creating one array from another array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35473174/creating-one-array-from-another-array-in-php) for how you can combine the match information for the same round in the PHP array.

If you want the query to return one row for each round, you can use `GROUP_CONCAT` to combine the `match` information into a single column:

```
SELECT r.poster, r.format, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(m.player, '(', m.score, ')') SEPARATOR ' vs ') AS players
FROM (SELECT round_id, poster, format
      FROM rounds
      ORDER BY round_id DESC
      LIMIT 2) AS r
JOIN matches AS m ON r.round_id = m.round_id
GROUP BY m.round_id
```

Comment: Thanks! but with your query i get differents arrays for each player, and the rounds info repeat in this arrays :(

Comment: You combine the rows for the same round in the PHP loop. The question I linked to shows how to do that.

Comment: Yeah i know, i fact i could do that but i want  an optmize way to do it. Because here i just show an example and the "rounds" table have more columns actually. At least not repeat the round information in each array?

Comment: I've added a version that uses `GROUP_CONCAT` to return the output in the format you showed.