# PHP Multi dimensional array from database

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I wanted to output a 3 dimensional array that will come from the Database. This is my database looks like:

[image]

Basically, I wanted my first array will be the `header_name` and under the header_name the `sub_header_name` will come then underneath is the `name`

eg:

```
    User Role Management => array(
                          '' => array (
                                   'Create User Role'
                               ) 
                            ),
   Config Management => array(
                         'Organisation' => array('Create Country','Create 
                                           Organisation'),
                          'Site' => array('Create Site','Edit Site') 
                        )
```

and here are my codes:

```
$getAllPermission = Permission::get();
$arrHeader = array();
$arrSubHeader = array();
$arrPermissions = array();
// $x = 0;
foreach($getAllPermission as $value){
    $title = $value->header_name;
    $sub_header_name = $value->sub_header_name;
    $permission_name = $value->name;
    if ($sub_header_name == ""){
        $sub_header_name = 0;
    }
    array_push($arrPermissions,$permission_name);
    $arrHeader[$title] = array($sub_header_name => array($arrPermissions));
    //$x++;

}
```

and my output was like this:

[image]

Comment: This question might get you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35473174/creating-one-array-from-another-array-in-php

Comment: I'm sorry for the mistake. I accidentaly hit "Enter"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pushing onto the same `$arrPermissions` array every time through the loop, that's why each of the roles gets a longer and longer copy of the permissions array.

You're overwriting `$arrHeader[$title]` each time through the loop instead of adding a new key to it.

Your desired output has a key of `''` for the empty `sub_header_name`, so I don't see why you have the `if` that sets `$sub_header_name = 0;`.

It should simply be:

```
foreach ($getAllPermissions as $value) {
    $arrHeader[$value->header_name][$value->sub_header_name][] = $value->name;
}
```

Comment: oh because of overwriting thats why I didn't get the correct data. Anyway, Thank you