# PHP merge several rows if duplicate value in cells

Tags: php, arrays, merge, duplicates

Im fetching rows out of a MySQL database. Each row contains a date and an amount (USD). Some of the dates are identical. I've been trying for hours to merge the amount of those rows with identical dates.

I have tried array_merge as well as serveral if-statements, foreach as well as while.

```
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {

  array_push($mergeDuplicateDate,
    array(                                   
      $row2[1], //date                                                                           
      $row2[2] //amount
    )
  );

};
```

If the output looks like:

```
06-25-2019, $5

06-25-2019, $10

06-26-2019, $2

06-26-2019, $1
```

I want it be summarized like:

```
06-25-2019, $15

06-26-2019, $3
```

I know it can't be that hard to do with PHP but I'm not super expirienced at programming. Thus far I could google up any problem that I came across. This time I just can't seem to find an answer. I really don't even know where to start solving this issue.

Thanks in advance to whoever breaks this down to me!

Comment: Make an associative array whose keys are the dates. Loop through the data and add each amount to the element with that key.

Comment: SHow us the query you are using to get this from the database. It would be much easier done as part of that query

Comment: Why don't you do it in the query? `SELECT date, SUM(amount) FROM table GROUP BY date`

Comment: I hope you don't really have `$` in the `amount` fields. You should store them as numbers, and add that when printing.

Comment: Judging by the example @Barmar the `sum()` may need to get rid of the `$` first :)

Comment: @barmar _I hope you don't really have $ in the amount fields_ But deep down where the sun does not shine you know they do :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'll just renewed the prescription on my rose-colored glasses :)

Comment: `SUM(REPLACE(amount, '$', ''))` if necessary

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35473174/creating-one-array-from-another-array-in-php for how to group array data.

Comment: @Barmar - The assoc array was the way to go for me! Problem solved. Thank you very much. Would upvote the comment if I only knew how ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Use a database, it is the least computationally expensive way to solve your problem. XD

```
SELECT date ,SUM(amount) FROM table GROUP BY date ASC
```

Comment: Ever since I LEFT JOIN'd multiple databases to begin with it seem to hard for my current skill level to figure out if and where I could include SUM. I've went with the PHP assoc array and it worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is using group by in MySQL query mentioned by @barmar in comments.

If you really want to do it in PHP you can use below code

```
$finalArray=[];
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {
  $finalArray[$row2[1]] = $finalArray[$row2[1]] ? $finalArray[$row2[1]] +$row2[2] : $row2[2];
};
```