# SQL - Add lines from other table as subentries to result (a join perhaps?)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having these two tables:

**wp_posts**

| ID | post_title | post_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Foo | product |
| 2 | Bar | product |
| 3 | Test | product |

**wp_postmeta**

| ID | post_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 150 | 1 | stock_ny | 150 |
| 151 | 1 | stock_la | 70 |
| 152 | 1 | stock_den | 90 |
| 153 | 1 | blah_blah | asdf |
| 160 | 1 | blah_blah2 | dfdfdf |
| 175 | 2 | stock_ny | 80 |
| 185 | 2 | stock_la | 20 |
| 195 | 2 | stock_den | 0 |
| 200 | 2 | blah_blah | asdf |
| 210 | 2 | blah_blah2 | dfdfdf |
| 220 | 3 | stock_ny | 86 |
| 230 | 3 | stock_la | 100 |
| 240 | 3 | stock_den | 99 |
| 250 | 3 | blah_blah | gddj |
| 260 | 3 | blah_blah2 | jdfdfj |

I'm calling it via PHP and WordPress. I've made it this far (not very long, I know):

```php
<?php
$query = 'SELECT ID, post_title, post_type';
$query .= 'FROM wp_posts';
$query .= 'WHERE post_type = "product" LIMIT 10';
$products = $wpdb->get_results( $query, OBJECT );
echo '<pre>';
print_r($products);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

And I would like an output like this:

```php
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [post_title] => Foo
        [post_type] => product
        [stocks] => [
            [stock_ny] => 150,
            [stock_la] => 70,
            [stock_den] => 90
        ]
    ),
[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 2
        [post_title] => Bar
        [post_type] => product
        [stocks] => [
            [stock_ny] => 80,
            [stock_la] => 20,
            [stock_den] => 0
        ]
    ),
[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 3
        [post_title] => Test
        [post_type] => product
        [stocks] => [
            [stock_ny] => 86,
            [stock_la] => 100,
            [stock_den] => 99
        ]
    )
```

I assume it's something with a join?

Comment: The column names in the table dont match the column names used in the query??? It really soes help if you sanity check your question before posting

Comment: Yes a JOIN would work, do give it a try

Comment: I fixed the names of the columns, so it matches my query (thanks for pointing that out). And can you give me a small push in the right direction? Which join should I use - and how do I merge them together? Perhaps a link to somewhere, where this is done? I'm shooting blanks, here. :-/  :see_no_evil:

Comment: You cannot make a query generate that data structure by itself. You will have to query the data and then create the required array from what SQL will allow

Comment: Use a join to put the related rows from the two tables in the same row of the results. Then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35473174/creating-one-array-from-another-array-in-php for how to create the nested arrays from the common keys.