# Merge parts of elements in multi-dimensional array that have the same key inside elements

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, iteration

I have a multi-dimensional array where multiple array elements will have the same key name inside.  Within these matching key array elements are data that I want to combine under one bucket, rather than having multiple buckets for essentially the same thing.  For example here is a look at the array in question:

```
    Array
    (
    [cityName] => Brooklyn
    [citySlug] => brooklyn
    [state] => NY
    [zipCode] => 11222
    [userType] => R
    [providerData] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [slug] => a
                    [name] => a
                    [technologyType] => Geo-satellite
                    [coverage] => 100
                    [reliabilityRating] => 2.87254902
                    [maximum_download_speed] => 50
                    [startingPrice] => 49.99
                    [priceBucket] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [slug] => b
                    [name] => b
                    [technologyType] => Cable
                    [coverage] => 100
                    [reliabilityRating] => 3.721088435
                    [maximum_download_speed] => 1000
                    [startingPrice] => 19.99
                    [priceBucket] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [slug] => c
                    [name] => c
                    [technologyType] => 5g-home
                    [coverage] => 99
                    [reliabilityRating] => 3.925925926
                    [maximum_download_speed] => 245
                    [startingPrice] => 50
                    [priceBucket] => 1
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [slug] => d
                    [name] => d
                    [technologyType] => 5g-home
                    [coverage] => 100
                    [reliabilityRating] => 3.915829146
                    [maximum_download_speed] => 300
                    [startingPrice] => 25
                    [priceBucket] => 1
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [slug] => d
                    [name] => d
                    [technologyType] => Dsl
                    [coverage] => 100
                    [reliabilityRating] => 3.915829146
                    [maximum_download_speed] => 15
                    [startingPrice] => 25
                    [priceBucket] => 1
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [slug] => d
                    [name] => d
                    [technologyType] => Fiber
                    [coverage] => 100
                    [reliabilityRating] => 3.915829146
                    [maximum_download_speed] => 2048
                    [startingPrice] => 25
                    [priceBucket] => 1
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [slug] => e
                    [name] => e
                    [technologyType] => Satellite
                    [coverage] => 100
                    [reliabilityRating] => 2.894736842
                    [maximum_download_speed] => 100
                    [startingPrice] => 69.99
                    [priceBucket] => 3
                )

        )

        )
```

Now for every slug value that matches under `providerData`, I want to combine those elements into one in a specific way such as this:

```
[<keep current index of first matched element>] => Array
                (
                    [slug] => d
                    [name] => d
                    [technologyType] => [
                        5g-home => [
                            'maximum_download_speed'=> <speed>,
                            'coverage' => <coverage>
                        ],
                        Dsl => [
                            'maximum_download_speed'=> <speed>,
                            'coverage' => <coverage>
                        ],
                        Fiber => [
                            'maximum_download_speed'=> <speed>,
                            'coverage' => <coverage>
                        ]
                    ]
                    [reliabilityRating] => 3.915829146
                    [startingPrice] => 25
                    [priceBucket] => 1
                )
```

Essentially just putting all the technology types and their respective data under one key inside the same bucket aka `slug`.

Here is my sorry attempt at trying to accomplish this:

```
 $mergedTechTypes = [];
    
  // Merge duplicate providers with different tech types
  foreach ($merged_providers_by_tech_type['providerData'] as $key => $value) {

      $next_provider = $merged_providers_by_tech_type['providerData'][$key + 1];
      $previous_provider = $merged_providers_by_tech_type['providerData'][$key - 1];

      if(empty($mergedTechTypes) && $value['slug'] === $next_provider['slug']) {
        $mergedTechTypes['technologyType'] = [
          $value['technologyType'] => [
          'maximum_download_speed' => $value['maximum_download_speed'],
          'coverage' => $value['coverage']
          ],
          $next_provider['technologyType'] => [
            'maximum_download_speed' => $value['maximum_download_speed'],
            'coverage' => $value['coverage']
          ]
        ];

        unset($merged_providers_by_tech_type['providerData'][$key]);

      } else if($value['slug'] === $next_provider['slug']) {
        $mergedTechTypes['technologyType'][$merged_providers_by_tech_type['providerData'][$key + 1]['technologyType']] = [
          'maximum_download_speed' => $value['maximum_download_speed'],
          'coverage' => $value['coverage']
        ];

        unset($merged_providers_by_tech_type['providerData'][$key]);

      } else if($value['slug'] === $previous_provider['slug']) {
        $mergedTechTypes['technologyType'][$merged_providers_by_tech_type['providerData'][$key + 1]['technologyType']] = [
          'maximum_download_speed' => $value['maximum_download_speed'],
          'coverage' => $value['coverage']
        ];
      }
}
```

This iteration attempt always leaves off one of the matches and its driving me crazy!! please help

Edit: My question is different from [Creating one array from another array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35473174/creating-one-array-from-another-array-in-php) because I DO NOT want to alter elements that have no matching ids.  Basically any unique slug key elements will stay the same

Comment: I've added more dupe targets that help to demonstrate the required technique of grouping and pushing grouped data into subarrays.  Please always post your sample input as the copy-pasted text from `var_export()` so that volunteers can instantly use your data in their sandbox environment.