# Removing array of arrays for certain inner values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Having this kind of array:

```
Array (
   [0] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
              [title] => "Test string"
              [lat] => "40.4211"
              [long] => "-3.70118"
              )
         )
   [1] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                  [title] => "Test string 2"
                  [lat] => "10.0"
                  [long] => "-23.0"
                  )
            [1] => Array (
                  [title] => "Test string 3"
                  [lat] => "10.0"
                  [long] => "-23.0"
                  )
          )
   [2] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
              [title] => "Test string 6"
              [lat] => "11.1"
              [long] => "7.7"
              )
         )
)
```

How can I get rid of that *array of arrays* for all the inner arrays that have length = 1?

My desired output would be:

```
Array (
   [0] => Array (
          [title] => "Test string"
          [lat] => "40.4211"
          [long] => "-3.70118"
   )
   [1] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                  [title] => "Test string 2"
                  [lat] => "10.0"
                  [long] => "-23.0"
                  )
            [1] => Array (
                  [title] => "Test string 3"
                  [lat] => "10.0"
                  [long] => "-23.0"
                  )
    )
    [2] => Array (
          [title] => "Test string 6"
          [lat] => "11.1"
          [long] => "7.7"
     )
)
```

Thanks in advance.

PS: I'm using PHP 5.3

Comment: Why did you accept an answer that didn't get you where you wanted? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47629049/group-array-by-inner-value-in-php and why are you not including that in this question. You have one array, and you asked for a way to change it, then you ask how to change the changed array. Isn't it better to do it correct to begin with instead of changing an already changed array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
  if(is_array($value) && count($value) ==1){
    $array[$key] = $value[0];
  }
}
```

Output:- https://eval.in/912263

*Or you can use **`Passing by Reference`** mechanism also:-*

```
foreach($array as &$value){
  if(is_array($value) && count($value) ==1){
    $value = $value[0];
  }
}
```

Output:- https://eval.in/912264

Reference:- [Passing by Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Answer (score 2):

Transform each value, if it has length 1 return its first child, else return the entire thing unchanged:

```
$arr = array_map(function ($a) { return count($a) == 1 ? $a[0] : $a; }, $arr);
```

Comment: Does this work in PHP 5.3? I'm getting a `syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')'`

Comment: [Sure.](https://3v4l.org/VIG4Q) Anonymous functions have been supported since exactly PHP 5.3.

Comment: It's strange, I'm getting that error when I'm using 5.3.6

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 2D arrays remain as is

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {      // Loop to result array
    if (count($value) <= 1) {           // Checks if array count is less than or equal to 1
        $array[$key] = reset($value);  // Reset to reduce from 2d array to 1d
    }
}

print_r($array);
```

Comment: I think this is not working, I'm only gettting one result instead the entire array.

Comment: Edited some typo. You can check now