# Accumulate in array php

Tags: php

I have an array which is multidimensional

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [id] => 2 [id_product_attribute] => 9 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [id_product_attribute] => 10 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [id] => 2 [id_product_attribute] => 8 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [id] => 3 [id_product_attribute] => 50 ) 
)
```

I want to convert this array into this form

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [id] => 2 [id_product_attribute] => Array(9,10,8) ) 
    [1] => Array ( [id] => 3 [id_product_attribute] => Array (50) )
)
```

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: what is the actual logic for it? it doesn't make any sense how you group those items without you explaining what you're trying to do.

Comment: @KasiaGogolek group by id, isn't it?

Comment: yes group by ID

Comment: the id was 2 for all the rows before the edit, hence my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php array group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706359/php-array-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop throught the first array and merge the values into the second one, then use `array_values` to order the first level array: ([Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/158417aa4dfc592d306fc8a57a9d55aae0e19e0f))

```
$orig = array( 
    0 => array( 'id' => 2, 'id_product_attribute' => 9 ),
    1 => array( 'id' => 2, 'id_product_attribute' => 10 ),
    2 => array( 'id' => 2, 'id_product_attribute' => 8 ),
    3 => array( 'id' => 3, 'id_product_attribute' => 50 )
);

$array = [];
foreach ($orig as $o) {
    if (!isset($array[$o['id']])) {
        $array[$o['id']] = ['id' => $o['id'], 'id_product_attribute' => []];
    }

    $array[$o['id']]['id_product_attribute'][] = $o['id_product_attribute'];
}

// to get the first array with indexes 0,1...
$result = array_values($array);

print_r($result);
```