# Sum parts of an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

this is quite beyond me. Appreciate some help.
I have an array in php like so:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [cust_id] => 1006
        [no_of_subs] => 2
        [dlv_id] => 1000
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [cust_id] => 1011
        [no_of_subs] => 3
        [dlv_id] => 1000
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [cust_id] => 1012
        [no_of_subs] => 5
        [dlv_id] => 1001
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [cust_id] => 1013
        [no_of_subs] => 6
        [dlv_id] => 1001
    )
```

I don't need the cust_id field. I just need to group the dlv_id and the sum of no_of_subs for each matching dlv_id. The result should look like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [dlv_id] => 1000
        [no_of_subs] => 5

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [cust_id] => 1011
        [no_of_subs] => 11

    )
```

Thank you for any help.

I don't understand the downvotes for this question. Am i doing it all wrong? Downvoting without a reason is not helping.

Comment: Use `foreach` and count values.

Comment: @schenker I suspect the downvotes are a product of you not including your coding attempt.  Normally, I don't answer questions without a coding attempt,  but I didn't like the upvoted answer, so I posted a superior approach so that future researchers didn't copy an indirect process.  If you did attempt to self-solve, please update your question.

Comment: Thank you. The downvotes bothered me if im getting it all wrong. I didn't post my attempt as it was producing a totally different result which i thought would be of no use to post here. Noted your advice. Thanks again.

Comment: It is not too late to edit your question.  We actually appreciate seeing your broken/failing code because in addition to providing our best suggested snippet, we can clear up any misconceptions you might have with your code.  I urge you to post it -- even if it is super-not-good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest, most efficient way to group and sum is to perform a single loop and assign temporary associative keys.

When a row is identified as a new `dlv_id` row, save the two desired elements, otherwise add the `no_of_subs` value to the pre-existing value.

Optionally, remove the temporary keys with `array_values()`.

Code ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/UIpKa))

```
$array = [
    ["cust_id" => 1006, "no_of_subs" => 2, "dlv_id" => 1000],
    ["cust_id" => 1011, "no_of_subs" => 3, "dlv_id" => 1000],
    ["cust_id" => 1012, "no_of_subs" => 5, "dlv_id" => 1001],
    ["cust_id" => 1013, "no_of_subs" => 6, "dlv_id" => 1001]
];

foreach ($array as $row) {
    if (!isset($result[$row["dlv_id"]])) {
        $result[$row["dlv_id"]] = ["dlv_id" => $row["dlv_id"], "no_of_subs" => $row["no_of_subs"]];
    } else {
        $result[$row["dlv_id"]]["no_of_subs"] += $row["no_of_subs"];
    }
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'dlv_id' => 1000,
    'no_of_subs' => 5,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'dlv_id' => 1001,
    'no_of_subs' => 11,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

- Using [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function, we can extract out `dlv_id` and `no_of_subs` separately in two different arrays, using `cust_id` as the key.
- Now, simply loop over the array of `dlv_id`, and if matching key found, add the `no_of_subs` to it, else set the value (for the first time).
- We use [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function to check if the key exists already or not.

Try the following:

```
// your input array is $input_array

// get all dlv_id maintaining the cust_id as index
$dlv_id = array_column($input_array, 'dlv_id', 'cust_id');

// get all no_of_subs maintaining the cust_id as index
$no_of_subs = array_column($input_array, 'no_of_subs', 'cust_id');

$output = array();

foreach ($dlv_id as $key => $value) {

    if (isset($output[$value]['dlv_id'])) {
        $output[$value]['dlv_id'] += $no_of_subs[$key];
    } else {
        $output[$value]['dlv_id'] += $no_of_subs[$key];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your thinking with that condition block?  See something odd there?  I hope my answer will inspire you in the future; your solution is iterating the input array 2 times, then iterating 1st manufactured array to perform the addition, and this is not efficient.  Not only is the solution inefficient, it generates Notices, and it doesn't generate the OP's desired output.  I have downvoted this answer to discourage future researchers from using it.  Demo: https://3v4l.org/irHJT