# Sort multi-dimensional array by Value

Tags: php, wordpress

Make catagory wordpress sort by group.

```
Array
(
[0] => WP_Term Object
    (
        [term_id] => 199
        [name] => 170
        [term_group] => 2
    )

[1] => WP_Term Object
    (
        [term_id] => 410
        [name] => 80s
        [term_group] => 2
    )

[2] => WP_Term Object
    (
        [term_id] => 66
        [name] => 8BIT
        [term_group] => 0
    )

[3] => WP_Term Object
    (
        [term_id] => 411
        [name] => adventure
        [term_group] => 0
    )
//... more then 100+
```

i focus term_group 
have create 12 group. 1 to 12

is not a group when use

```
$tags = get_tags(); //array above
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    if ($tag->term_group==1) {
        echo "group 1";
        echo $tag->name;
    }

    if ($tag->term_group==2) {
        echo "group 2";
        echo $tag->name;
    }

    // .... until group 12
}
```

this array can output like

> group 1  xxx aaa bbb
>
> group 2 170 80s
>
> group 3 ....

Comment: you need `usort` function

Comment: Possible of duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/how-to-sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php array group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706359/php-array-group)

Comment: `group 1 xxx aaa bbb` is un-understandable to me

Comment: Is this array has the term_group from 1 to 12 or something other.
Can you please share the array of an object as the format of an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't able to access your $tags array. Because it is in array of object format.

So I just developed the code. You may try like below.

```
<?php
$dataArray = array();
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    for($i=1;$i<13;$i++){
        if ($tag->term_group==$i) {
            $dataArray[$i] = $tag;
            continue 2; 
        }
    }
}
// Just print this $dataArray and check this array contain the term_group sets.

for($i=1;$i<13;$i++){
    echo "group".$i;
    if($dataArray[$i]){
        foreach ($dataArray[$i] as $key => $value) {
             echo $value['term_group'];
        }
        echo "<br/>";
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: add if for($i=1;$i<13;$i++){
    echo "group".$i;
    if ($dataArray[$i]) {
    foreach ($dataArray[$i] as $key => $value) {
 print_r($value);
    }
    }
    echo "<br/>";
}

Answer (score 0):

solve

```
$group = array();
foreach ( $tags as $value ) {
    $group[$value->term_group][] = $value;
}
echo "group 1";
foreach($group['1'] as $result) {
    echo $result->name;
}
```