# PHP - sorting arrays in group

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have trouble sorting my array result in a different way. I have written an API call that returns specified results but not in the right way.

So it gives me:

```
{
"success": true,
"data": [
    [
        "Question",
        [
            "Answer"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "Question",
        [
            "Answer 2"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "Question 2",
        [
            "Answer 3"
        ]
    ]
],
"message": null
```

}

And I want to return a group of answers for that question like:

```
{
"success": true,
"data": [
    [
        "Question",
        [
            "Answer"
        ],
        [
            "Answer 2"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "Question 2",
        [
            "Answer 3"
        ]
    ]
],
"message": null
}
```

And my code looks like:

```
$questions = $this->getQRepository()->findAll();

$mappedQuestions = [];

foreach ($questions as $question){

    $title = $question->getTitle();

    $mappedQuestions[] = [
        $title,
        [
            $question->getAnswer()
        ]
    ];
}

return $mappedQuestions;
```

It gives me the result where it groups every question with answer by id but I need to group all answers by question. The result returns correctly but sorting is wrong.

Comment: in your first array, there is 2 index with name question...

and your sorting end like question, question, question 2...

Comment: and the solution you asked for is

sorting like question, question2 where is another key with name question is gone? what you want to do with it?

Comment: Can you please provide sample response for `$questions = $this->getQRepository()->findAll();`?

Comment: It returns all data from questions table and that is a data that I am trying to sort. @Olawale

Comment: If the data are from the db, then just do group by query

Comment: I did it by groupBy but it returns just one answer per question not all of them. @AfifZafri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work, but I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for. 
So first, modified your current looping and `$mappedQuestions` array structure like this:

```
$mappedQuestions = [];

foreach ($questions as $question){

    $mappedQuestions[] = array(
                               'title' => $question->getTitle(), 
                               'answer' => $question->getAnswer()
                          );
}
```

After that, iterate the array one more time to create a new array that will group together the elements based on the array key, which in this case is "title".

```
$sorted = array();
foreach ($mappedQuestions as $element) {
    $sorted[$element['title']][] = $element['answer'];
}

return $sorted;
```

The final output of `$sorted` is:

```
{
   "Question":[
      "Answer",
      "Answer 2"
   ],
   "Question 2":[
      "Answer 3"
   ]
```

The sort looping code is actually from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706359/php-array-group).

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

you need to iterate 2 loops to achieve it, I took your JSON in `$json` variable and then proceed as,

```
$json = '{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        [
            "Question",
            [
                "Answer"
            ]
        ],
        [
            "Question",
            [
                "Answer 2"
            ]
        ],
        [
            "Question 2",
            [
                "Answer 3"
            ]
        ]
    ],
    "message": null
    }';

$arr = (array) json_decode($json, true);

foreach($arr['data'] AS $a){
    $newArr[ $a[ 0 ] ][] = array( $a[ 1 ][ 0 ] );
}

foreach($newArr AS $key => $a){
    $newArr2[] = array_merge(array($key), array_values($a));
}

$finalArr = array('success' => $arr['success'], 'data' => $newArr2, 'message' => $arr['message']);

print_r($finalArr); // this is final o/p which you want,
```

Note: this is may be not correct answer, but by this now you have an idea how to do,

Comment: This is one possible solution. Thanks a lot for feedback. @harishsharma