# Check if values are same in array, if not store as different orders in php

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, foreach, yii2-advanced-app

I Am posting this question as I didn't get a solution while searching here.
Here is my question

I have an array coming after submitting data from the view page, its a list of product user has selected to book certain dates(start_date and end_date). 
like he might have selected 3 different products on the same date, or all the 3 products on different date starting date and return date.

Now I have an array in which I have all the products selected by a user with **start_date and end_date** and other product related information.

Before Storing these products as ORDERS, I need to check

1. If multiple products have **same** start_date and end_date, then it becomes **one order**.
2. If multiple products have **different** start_date and end_date, then it becomes **different orders**.

Now how will I check if these products have the same start_date and end_date or different?

for example.. this is an array

```
 Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 15
        [start_date] => 2019-05-15
        [end_date] => 2019-05-16
        [status] => in_stock
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 16
        [start_date] => 2019-05-15
        [end_date] => 2019-05-16
        [status] => out_of_stock
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 17
        [start_date] => 2019-05-17
        [end_date] => 2019-05-18
        [status] => in_stock
    )
 )
```

These are 3 different products, here 2 products are booked for same date product_id[15,16]-> so it becomes **one Order**.

And the other product_id number 17 becomes one second Order.

Edit...

I have added status to the array now, lets say i have 2 orders on same date product_id[15,16], now it has to sort based on two condition,

1. If multiple order have same start_date and end_date, then it becomes single order/array, which i have achieved by using accepted answer.
2. Now lets say after sorting i get an array in which i have 2 different products, one is **in_stock** and other is **out_of_stock**, now it should again become two different orders.

Please give some solution, as I am stuck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by the array with the same keys, which in your case is the start and end date. Maybe something like this:

```
$data = array(); // this is your array
$result = array();
foreach ($data as $element) {
    /* this will create an array that have start and end date as the key. 
    So, order with same start and end date will be grouped as 1.*/
    $result[$element['start_date']." to ".$element['end_date']][] = $element;
}

print_r($result); // do what you want
```

original codes [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12706456/5784900).

Comment: Thanks, will use and see.

Comment: your answer worked for me, but i have edited my question with one more requirement, can you please look into that?

Comment: just add the stock status to the key. 

$result[$element['start_date']." to ".$element['end_date']."_".$element['status']][] = $element;

the array key would look like this: 
"2019-05-15 to 2019-05-16_in_stock"
"2019-05-15 to 2019-05-16_out_of_stock"

Answer (score 1):

> **[array_walk()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)** - **Apply a user supplied function to every member of an array**

You can use `array_walk` and iterate through the `array` to group the `arrays` by `start_date`. `$arr` is your array.

```
$res = [];
array_walk($arr, function($v, $k) use (&$arr,&$res){
  $nextKey = array_key_exists($k+1, $arr) ? ($k+1) : '';
  if(!empty($nextKey) && 
     $v['start_date'] == $arr[$nextKey]['start_date'] &&
     $v['end_date'] == $arr[$nextKey]['end_date']
  ){
     $res[] = [$v, $arr[$nextKey]];
     unset($arr[$nextKey]);
  }else{
     $res[] = [$v];
  }  
});
echo '<pre>';
print_r($res);
```

For the total number of order use `count($res)`

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this will do only for start_date, i wanted for both dates.

Comment: you mean the start_date and end_date both compared to another array?

Comment: @RakeshJakhar if the dates continue one it's showing the correct answer, but for order dates with different row it s not showing correctly for example: row 1 startdate :07-05-19 row 2 startdate:08-05-19 row3 startdate: 07-05-19 in this case row 1 and row 3 have the same values but it is showing 3 different dates but if i move row 3 to row2 it is working fine bec it is coming next to next.