# Group a query whit joins using PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I have this query

```
SELECT qu.nom_questao, qu.tipo_reposta ,rq.des_resposta 
    FROM questao qu 
    inner join questionario_questao qq on qu.id_questao=qq.id_questao 
    inner join questionario q on qq.id_questionario = q.id_questionario 
    left join resposta_questao rq on qu.id_questao=rq.id_questao 
    WHERE q.id_questionario=1
```

and [result of this select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uH9TG.png)
i want that  group by column nom_questao having a result like

```
[
    0:[TesteFechada
    [0:opcao1
    1:opcao2
    2:opcao3
    3:opcao4
    ] 
    ],
    1:[TesteAberta
    [
    0:opcao1
    1:opcao2
    2:opcao3
    3:opcao4
    ]
],
    3:[Range[
    0:21
    1:35
    ]
]
```

is there any way the PDO can do this?

Comment: No, PDO will not do this for you. Just use a loop in PHP to create the groups. Something like what's described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706359/php-array-group

Comment: An ORDER BY clause would be a good start.

Comment: @NigelRen  at the end he has to use php `while()`or `foreach()` loop to get his desired result, because with query he can't get his desired output

Comment: fetch the record, apply the loop and get your desired result

Comment: @AlivetoDie The idea of reading the data and then processing the array is a waste of time, read each row and place it int the structure your after in one go.

Comment: @NigelRen  didn't get you. please explain?

Comment: @NigelRen you mean i build my object using foreach??