# MYSQL PHP Array grouping

Tags: php, mysql

Having trouble wrapping my head around this conceptually. Still new to this. Basically I have this return from my database :

```
array (size=456)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[358]
      public 'id' => string '2432' (length=4)
      public 'symbol' => string '.AMLP' (length=14)
      public 'last' => string '0.01' (length=4)
      public 'volume' => string '3690' (length=4)
      public 'the_date' => string '2019-09-13' (length=10)
      public 'the_screener' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'notes' => string 'notes here' (length=149)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[726]
      public 'id' => string '2417' (length=4)
      public 'symbol' => string '.ARCC' (length=14)
      public 'last' => string '2.25' (length=4)
      public 'volume' => string '1633' (length=4)
      public 'the_date' => string '2019-09-13' (length=10)
      public 'the_screener' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'notes' => string 'notes' (length=60)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[726]
      public 'id' => string '2447' (length=4)
      public 'symbol' => string '.ARCC' (length=14)
      public 'last' => string '2.25' (length=4)
      public 'volume' => string '1633' (length=4)
      public 'the_date' => string '2019-09-12' (length=10)
      public 'the_screener' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'notes' => string 'notes here 3' (length=60)
  3 =>
```

What I'm trying to do with PHP is create an object/array that I can work with that displays these items like

```
AMLP 1 found on dates 2019-09-13
ARCC 2 found on dates 2019-09-13, 2019-09-12
```

In the end I would display these in a table, but conceptually this is what I'm trying to do.

I've tried creating an array in my foreach I use to display this information in a table, but I was thinking about it and it's probably better to just use the same query data and break it down separately.

So I'd like to create an array like :

```
    Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [symbol] => ARCC 
            [dates] => Array
                (
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            2019-09-13
                            2019-09-12
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php array group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706359/php-array-group)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider your array is `$arrDates`. If you want to access properties like object properties

```
$arrFinal = [];
foreach ($arrDates as $intKey => $obj){
    $strSymbol = getSubSymbol($obj->symbol);
    if(!isset($arrFinal[$strSymbol])) {
        $arrFinal[$strSymbol] = [ 'id' => $obj->id, 'symbol' => $obj->symbol];
    }

    $arrFinal[$strSymbol]['dates'][] = $obj->the_date;
 }

// Now loop throuh arrFinal and do print the statements you want.
foreach($arrFinal as $strSubSymbol => $arrData){
    echo $strSubSymbol . ' '. count($arrData['dates']) . ' found on dates ' . implode(',', $arrData['dates']). PHP_EOL;
}
```

Function to get the desired subpart of symbol

```
function getSubSymbol($symbol_original){
    $symbol = preg_split('/(?=\d)/', $symbol_original, 2); //get everything up until first number or the date in the string in this case.
    $symbol_here = substr($symbol[0], 1);
    return $symbol_here;
}
```

Comment: Hi Jitendra . I haven't been able to full go through but right now this is the return :

`Array
(
    [] => Array
        (
            [id] => 
            [symbol] => 
            [dates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 
                    [6] => 
                    [7] => 
                    [8] => `

The query results come into $products also.

Comment: I hope so as you have object inside, try the second one in which I've mentioned that

Comment: I think I forgot an important part, but I think we're on the right track here. Thank you for your help with this by the way. 

The symbol is returned like this : AMLP191101C10 or like this ARCC210115C17

Notice that the symbol is the first letters before the first number. I think I need to add that in some way for this to work, right? It's spitting out the array, but no matches.

Comment: Do you mean, here we are comparing `AMLP` but it can be `AMLP191101C10 ` or `AMLP1913433C39`, is that so?

Comment: Yes, just the first letters before the first number in the string. Yes your extrapolation is correct above. The output is still not showing any matches as before. I think because the symbol from what I'm reading in the script. Can you explain the index above. Maybe I'm just not understanding what you mean by that.

Comment: What if we can take only alphabets from starting? Would that work?

Comment: Yes that should do it. Any letters starting left to right efore the first number.