# Concatenate values according to the same key value

Tags: php, arrays, implode, php-7.2

Im some new in PHP and I want to join values according to `drug` key with the same `id`.

My array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17
            [drug] => Clobazam
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 23
            [drug] => Dexametasona
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 23
            [drug] => Diiodohidroxiquinoleína
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 25
            [drug] => Diclofenac,dietilamina
        )
```

Expected output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17
            [drug] => Clobazam
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 23
            [drug] => Dexametasona, Diiodohidroxiquinoleína
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 25
            [drug] => Diclofenac,dietilamina
        )
```

Comment: Do you get this data from your database?

Comment: No, from a diferent xml files. This array is a that a fusion of several files.

Comment: Loop over your data, put the items into a new array. While you are doing so, check if an item with the same id value already exists in the new array - if so, you need to take the current `drug` value of that item, combine it into an array with the `drug` from the current record, and assign the whole thing _to_ the `drug` key of the already existing item again.

Comment: This should give you a good hint. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706359/php-array-group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array = [
    [
        'id' => 17,
        'drug' => 'Clobazam'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 23,
        'drug' => 'Dexametasona'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 23,
        'drug' => 'Diiodohidroxiquinoleína'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 25,
        'drug' => 'Clobazam'
    ]
];

$result = [];

foreach ($array as $item) {
    $id = $item['id'];
    $drug = $item['drug'];
    if (isset($result[$id])) {
        $result[$id]['drug'] .= ', ' . $drug;
    } else {
        $result[$id] = $item;
    }
}

$result = array_values($result);

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function for to retrieve your expected output:

```
function collect_same_id(&$data){

        $tmp = [];
        $i = 0;
        foreach($data as $ind=>$rec){

             if(!array_key_exists($rec['id'],$tmp)){ 
                $tmp[$rec['id']] = $i;
                $i++;
            } else {
                $data[$tmp[$rec['id']]]['drug'] .= ', '.$rec['drug'];
                unset($data[$ind]); 
            } 
        }
        sort($data);
}

collect_same_id($data);

print_r($data);
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/jZL7v)**

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17
            [drug] => Clobazam
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 23
            [drug] => Dexametasona, Diiodohidroxiquinoleína
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 25
            [drug] => Diclofenac,dietilamina
        )

)
```

Here `&` mutate your original array, you can read about [references here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php). Appending values done with concatenation. Information about how does `array_key_exists` works you can read [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php).

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this as it is not efficient. Also, sorting the dataset `$data` inside the loop of `$data` itself should be purely avoided.

Comment: @vivek_23, it's not necessary, I know. Just thinking about other stuff