# php join by commas values that have the same key

Tags: php

I want to be able to join by commas values that have the same key.

**I have this code:**

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [user123] => 50877214
            )
    
        [1] => Array
            (
                [user123] => 7776057
            )
    
        [2] => Array
            (
                [user456] => 53445145
            )
    
        [3] => Array
            (
                [user456] => 19487054
            )
    )
```

**I would like to convert it to:**

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [user123] => "50877214,7776057",
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [user456] => "53445145,19487054",
            )
    )
```

**My code:**

```
$arr  = array_map(null, ...$arr);
$temp = array_map(function ($item) {
    return implode(",", $item);
}, $arr);
print_r($temp);die;
```

**Result:**

```
Array ( [0] => 50877214,7776057,53445145,19487054 )
```

apparently it is not possible to group by the key...

Comment: `array_map` works only with values. Have you tried a boring old `foreach`?

Comment: Does every nested array only have one key? You can use `array_keys($element)[0]` to get that key.

Comment: Why are you creating a multidimensional result, instead of a single associative array?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/59214059/2943403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also `array_reduce` can be used here:

```
$res = array_reduce($arr, function ($acc, $el) {
    $key = array_key_first($el);
    $acc[$key] .= ($acc[$key] ? ',':'') . $el[$key];
    return $acc;
}, $acc);
    
var_export($res);
```

[Execute PHP online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=f4a8f66e9a23844d9ea5c1583efc1cd5&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Result:

```
array (
  'user123' => '50877214,7776057',
  'user456' => '53445145,19487054',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by creating an associative array whose values are arrays. Then you can convert that into the desired result by creating nested arrays and using `implode()` to join with commas.

```
$assoc = [];
foreach ($array as $nested) {
    foreach ($nested as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($assoc[$key])) {
            $assoc[$key][] = $value;
        } else {
            $assoc[$key] = [$value];
        }
    }
}

$result = [];
foreach ($assoc as $key => $value) {
    $result[] = [$key => implode(',', $value)];
}
```

I actually recommend stopping at the first step. An array of arrays with different keys is generally difficult to work with (as you've already discovered).

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, though I thought this could still be helpful.

```php
$data = [
    ["user123" => 50877214],
    ["user123" => 7776057],
    ["user456" => 53445145],
    ["user456" => 19487054]
];

$keys = [];
$result = [];

array_walk_recursive($data, function ($value, $key) use (&$keys, &$result) {
    if (!in_array($key, $keys)) {
        $keys[] = $key;
        $result[array_search($key, $keys)] = [$key => ""];
    }
    $result[array_search($key, $keys)][$key] .= $value. ",";
});

print_r($result);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user123] => 50877214,7776057,
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user456] => 53445145,19487054,
        )

)
 */
```

### Addendum

Otherwise, if you just want the result as a *"flattened"* array, the solution below could do the trick.

```php
$data = [
    ["user123" => 50877214],
    ["user123" => 7776057],
    ["user456" => 53445145],
    ["user456" => 19487054]
]; 

$keys = [];
$result = [];

array_walk_recursive($data, function ($value, $key) use (&$keys, &$result) {
    if (!in_array($key, $keys)) {
        $keys[] = $key;
        $result[$key] = "";
    }
    $result[$key] .= $value. ",";
});

print_r($result);

/*
Array
(
    [user123] => 50877214,7776057,
    [user456] => 53445145,19487054,
)
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through inner-arrays with *foreach* and another loop to iterate over *key-value* pairs, *`$key`* which is *user id* (e.g. user123). check if the `$key` in `$arr` which first time will not be there, So store its *value*, Second time will be there So accumulate its values by separator commas`,`...

```php
$array = [
    ["user123" => 50877214],
    ["user123" => 7776057],
    ["user456" => 53445145],
    ["user456" => 19487054]
];

$arr = [];
foreach ($array as $inner) {
    foreach ($inner as $key => $value) {
        if(array_key_exists($key, $arr)){
            $arr[$key] .= ','.$value;
        }else{
            $arr[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
```

**Prints*:*

```
Array
(
    [user123] => 50877214,7776057
    [user456] => 53445145,19487054
)
```

Nevertheless, If you want the array be indexed, Just do another variable `$res`, loop through `$arr` and store its *key-value* pairs to `$res`.

```php
$res = [];
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $res[] = [$key => $value];
}
print_r($res);
```

**Output*:*

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user123] => 50877214,7776057
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user456] => 53445145,19487054
        )

)
```