# Split the array in to sub arrays based on array key value

Tags: php, arrays

I am facing one issue while splitting array by key value. My array looks like below :-

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 6
        [brand_id] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 1
        [brand_id] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 5
        [brand_id] => 1

    )

)
```

Now i want to filter split the array based on brand_id. My expected output is like below:-

```
Array(
[0] => Array(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 6
        [brand_id] => 2
    )
)
[1] => Array(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 1
        [brand_id] => 1
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 5
        [brand_id] => 1
  
    )
)
)
```

My Input array is stored in $proArray variable

My attempt below:-

```
$brands = array();
    foreach ($proArr as $key => $pro) {
        $brands[] = $pro['brand_id'];
    }
    $brands = array_unique($brands);
    
    $ckey = 0;
    foreach($brands as $brand){
        
    }
```

Comment: Have __you__ tried anything?

Comment: yes but not working

Comment: i have used loop first to get all brands and using array_unique and saved in one array and after that using loop over brand and again loop on Proarray

Comment: Show your attempt, please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to group subarrays by a column value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706359/how-to-group-subarrays-by-a-column-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it with simple `foreach()` loop to **push** values based on your **brand_id** like below-

```
$key = 'brand_id';
$return = array();
foreach($array as $v) {
     $return[$v[$key]][] = $v;
}
print_r($return);
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/bHuWV

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        'product_id' => 6,
        'brand_id' => 2
    ),
    array(
        'product_id' => 1,
        'brand_id' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'product_id' => 5,
        'brand_id' => 1

    )
);
$res = [];
foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
    $res[$value['brand_id']][] = $value;
$res = [...$res];
print_r($res);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 6
                    [brand_id] => 2
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 1
                    [brand_id] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 5
                    [brand_id] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: There is no reason for the if. All you do is the same thing that the next line does. Create a new array and add the value