# Group 2d array data by two columns then sum a third column to create a 3d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, grouping

I need to group the data in my 2d array by one column then by another column and sum a third column in each subset.

Input data:

```
$orders = [
    ["date" => "20230320", "model" =>  "ABC", "quantity"  => 1],
    ["date" => "20230320", "model" =>  "DEF", "quantity"  => 2],
    ["date" => "20230320", "model" =>  "ABC", "quantity"  => 3],
    ["date" => "20230320", "model" =>  "DEF", "quantity"  => 5],
    ["date" => "20230321", "model" =>  "ABC", "quantity"  => 1],
];
```

Specifically, I'd like to restructure the data to group by `date` as the first level keys, then group by unique `model` subarray where the `quantity` value are summed.

Desired result:

```
[
    20230320 => [
        ['date' => 20230320, 'model' => 'ABC', 'quantity' => 4]
        ['date' => 20230320, 'model' => 'DEF', 'quantity' => 7]
    ],
    20230321 => [
        ['date' => 20230321, 'model' => 'ABC', 'quantity' => 1]
    ]
]
```

After struggling some hours, I was able to reach my goal proceeding step by step, but I'm wondering if a simpler solution exist.

This is the complete working code:

```
// STEP 1 - GROUP ITEMS BY DATE
$orders2 = array();
foreach($orders as $order) {
    $date = $order['date'];
    $orders2[$date][] = $order;
} 
print_r ($orders2);

// STEP 2 - GROUP ITEMS BY MODEL AND SUM QUANTITY
$orders3 = array();
foreach($orders2 as $items) {
    foreach($items as $item) {
        $date = $item['date'];
        $model = $item['model'];
        if(empty($orders3[$date][$model])) {
            $orders3[$date][$model][] = $item;
        } else {
            $orders3[$date][$model][0]['quantity'] += $item['quantity'];    
        }
    } 
}
print_r ($orders3);

// STEP 3 - REMOVE NOT NECESSARY MODEL LEVEL
$orders4 = array();
foreach($orders3 as $items) {
    foreach($items as $item) {
        $date = $item[0]['date'];
        $orders4[$date][] = $item[0];
    } 
}
print_r ($orders4);
```

What do you suggest? Any simpler way to obtain the same result in a more straightforward way?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, this would be a great question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Please don't actively post in both places, I don't think that's a good idea. For Code Review you also need to add what you actually use the code for.

Comment: [How to group by and sum a multi-dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24032585/2943403) is a similar/related question if you wanted to build a 3d associative array. @madimar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great opportunity to implement reference variables.

There are two separate groupings in this task:

1. Group by the date and
2. Group by the model within each date.

This can be done by temporarily generating an associative array of associative arrays, but then the populated array will need to be re-iterated to re-index the subarray keys.

Instead, declare references to the date-model subsets, and push them into the result.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/FuEmW))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $key = $row['date'] . ' ' . $row['model']; 
    if (!isset($ref[$key])) {
        $ref[$key] = $row;
        $result[$row['date']][] = &$ref[$key];
    } else {
        $ref[$key]['quantity'] += $row['quantity'];
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

In the above, date and model values are joined into a single string to form a "composite key". New entries only get pushed into the result array if the unique combination of date-model values is encountered for the first time.  If the composite key was already encountered in an earlier result, then only the quantity of the current row is added to the quantity of the reference's quantity.

Comment: I really like your solution @mickmackusa, it maintains original logics and it works fine in a single step. Your concept of composite key is also extendible to other columns and this is very good. Really thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following to achieve this:

1. Unique the dates and flip the array for the expected keys
2. Walk the array and query the key for the associated date
3. Unique the models
4. Loop and sum the quantities

---

```
# Flip the dates and map to get the desired array structure
$dates = array_map(fn() => [], array_flip(array_unique(array_column($orders, 'date'))));

# Loop the dates where $key is the date
foreach ($dates as $key => &$value)
{
    # Filter the array of which dates correspond
    $query = array_filter($orders, fn($order) => (int) $order['date'] === $key);
    
    # Unique the models and array_sum on the quantity
    $value = array_map(fn($model) => [
        'date' => $key,
        'model' => $model,
        'quantity' => array_sum(array_column(array_filter($query, fn($q) => $q['model'] === $model), 'quantity')),
    ], array_unique(array_column($query, 'model')));
}
```

See it working on [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/WPVP4) - Updated to just remove the "overhead". I missread your question thinking you didn't have a working solution but I'll just leave this here as an alternative solution.

Comment: This is **purely my opinion**, but I prefer the original code. This code seems very difficult to maintain, and an exercise in trying to use as many different array functions as possible. Also, from the very limited testing I did, this code seems to take twice as long as the original.

Comment: I agree, you could achieve the same with loops but I started with the array_walk and didn't bother going back - you could optimise it quite easily but its there only to answer the OP. I appreciate your feedback however @KIKOSoftware - Also, looking back,  I didn't even realise he was asking for a code review, I just read the top part of the question lol.

Comment: Thanks for being a sport. I do appreciate the creativity. 

Answer (score 0):

My turn to put something down. I like simple code, because it's easy to understand and maintain. I went for this:

```php
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    extract($row);
    if (isset($result[$date][$model])) {
        $result[$date][$model]['quantity'] += $quantity;
    } else {
        $result[$date][$model] = $row;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

The output is:

```php
array (
  20230320 => 
  array (
    'ABC' => 
    array (
      'date' => '20230320',
      'model' => 'ABC',
      'quantity' => 4,
    ),
    'DEF' => 
    array (
      'date' => '20230320',
      'model' => 'DEF',
      'quantity' => 7,
    ),
  ),
  20230321 => 
  array (
    'ABC' => 
    array (
      'date' => '20230321',
      'model' => 'ABC',
      'quantity' => 1,
    ),
  ),
)
```

See: https://3v4l.org/s9d2d

There are two things to remark about this:

- This isn't the output you requested. I add an extra level of meaningful indexes, as you can see. I don't see the harm in that, but it could spoil things for you.
- It is generally discouraged to use `extract()`, because you often extract more than you need, and it can create globals you don't expect. If you use it, use it in a function or method. Here we use everything we extract, so I think I can get away with it...

Apart from that I think I have achieved simplicity. That's mainly thanks to the code of mickmackusa.