# Re-grouping array into multidimensional using several values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

### What I have:

```
array(
    [
        'id' => 12, 'group' => 'abc', 'name' => 'Lorem',
    ],
    [
        'id' => 12, 'group' => 'def', 'name' => 'Ipsum',
    ],
    [
        'id' => 34, 'group' => 'ghi', 'name' => 'Dolor',
    ],
    [
        'id' => 34, 'group' => 'jkl', 'name' => 'Sit',
    ],
    [
        'id' => 34, 'group' => 'mno', 'name' => 'Amet',
    ],
);
```

### What I want:

```
array (size=2)
  12 => 
    array (size=2)
      'abc' => 
        array (size=3)
          'id' => int 12
          'group' => string 'abc' (length=3)
          'name' => string 'Lorem' (length=5)
      'def' => 
        array (size=3)
          'id' => int 12
          'group' => string 'def' (length=3)
          'name' => string 'Ipsum' (length=5)
  34 => 
    array (size=3)
      'ghi' => 
        array (size=3)
          'id' => int 34
          'group' => string 'ghi' (length=3)
          'name' => string 'Dolor' (length=5)
      'jkl' => 
        array (size=3)
          'id' => int 34
          'group' => string 'jkl' (length=3)
          'name' => string 'Sit' (length=3)
      'mno' => 
        array (size=3)
          'id' => int 34
          'group' => string 'mno' (length=3)
          'name' => string 'Amet' (length=4)
```

### What I tried:

The obvious:

```
$sorted = array();
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $sorted[$product['id']][$product['group']] = $product;
}
$products = $sorted;
unset($sorted);
```

But then, in an effort to [avoid `foreach()` loops](https://www.giorgiosironi.com/2010/02/stop-writing-foreach-cycles.html), and with help of [@atomrc's answer to *How to group subarrays by a column value?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706359/how-to-group-subarrays-by-a-column-value/44541758#44541758), I came up with this:

```
$sorted = array_reduce($products, function ($accumulator, $element) {
    $accumulator[$element['id']][] = $element;
    return $accumulator;
}, []);
array_walk($sorted, function(&$item) {
    $item = array_reduce($item, function ($accumulator, $element) {
        $accumulator[$element['group']] = $element;
        return $accumulator;
    }, []);
});
```

So while the above looks cool and all, it's also much bigger and seemingly more complex than that foreach. This is probably because my experience with `array_reduce()` is limited. Is there a way to have the array grouped in one go? For example, in the first `array_reduce()` call.

Comment: The obvious looks pretty good to me. What's the issue with using a `foreach` loop? `array_reduce` and `array_walk` just do one internally anyway...

Comment: Code that you instinctively understand when you have to change something about it later, is often worth more than one using “more fancy” functions.

Comment: `foreach` can actually be faster in some situations than using PHP's built in array functions (based on peoples benchmarks in the past) so there's no reason to avoid `foreach`. It of course depends on many factors. Using `foreach` is absolutely fine though.

Comment: There is no any reason to awoid `foreach` in your case and use callback-functions. Becasue `foreach` faster, with less overhead, with shorter and much more understandable code. Do not blindly follow the recommendation from that article to awoid `foreach` everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I don't see an issue with the `foreach` solution, but if you want to use `array_reduce` you can simply use the inner code from the `foreach` loop:

```
$grouped = array_reduce($products, function ($c, $v) {
    $c[$v['id']][$v['group']] = $v;
    return $c;
}, []);

print_r($grouped);
```

The output of this code is the same as your `foreach` loop.

Note that this (and your `foreach` loop) won't deal correctly with the situation where there is more than one array with the same `id` and `group` values. For example, if we extend `$products`:

```
$products[] =     [
        'id' => 34, 'group' => 'jkl', 'name' => 'Consectetur',
    ];
```

Then the first `jkl` group value gets overwritten by the second. To deal with this you need to make each group an array e.g.

```
$grouped = array_reduce($products, function ($c, $v) {
    $c[$v['id']][$v['group']][] = $v;
    return $c;
}, []);

print_r($grouped);
```

In this case the `jkl` group then looks like:

```
[jkl] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 34
                [group] => jkl
                [name] => Sit
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 34
                [group] => jkl
                [name] => Consectetur
            )
    )
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Qvf6J)